# Converting a circuit from Multisim into a PCB

Tags: pcb, multisim

I drew this metal detector circuit in Multisim.  How can I make a PCB board from it?

Is there an option in Multisim to convert it to PCB or do I need another program?

[image: multisim circuit for metal detector]

Comment: You will need a separate PCB pacakge.  There are a number of PCB packages that integrate with Multisim.  You could improve your question by including information about what experience you have with making PCBs.

Answer (score 7):

[NI Ultiboard](https://www.ni.com/ultiboard/) is the PCB layout counterpart to Multisim and allows you to layout PCBs from a Multisim schematic.

Answer (score 1):

> ## Transfering to Other PCB Layout Packages

If you are using a PCB layout package other than Ultiboard, you can create files in the necessary formats for transfer to the following third party layout packages:

• OrCAD 
• PADS Layout 2005 
• P-CAD 
• Protel

[image]

Complete the following steps to transfer the circuit design to a third party layout package: 
1. Select Transfer»Export to PCB Layout. A standard Windows Save As dialog box appears. 2. Navigate to the desired folder, enter a file name, choose the desired manufacturer from the drop-down list and click Save.

Multisim creates a file of the appropriate format that can then be loaded into the layout package of your choice.

Answer (score 0):

You will need a specific tool such as Eagle (free or at least trial for small PCBs) or Altium Designer (kind of costly).

Another alternative would be to use RS-Component's design tool: http://www.rs-online.com/designspark/electronics/deu/page/designspark-pcb-home-page

Answer (score 0):

I don't think multisim supports this feature. I recommend using Eagle. It's a tool which allows you to draw schematics and layout pcbs. You can download it from here: http://www.cadsoftusa.com/download-eagle/?language=en

Answer (score 0):

Of course multism supports to design your own PCB. It has Ultiboard package which can enable us do our PCB. But, be careful while transferring your schematic to ultiboard, since some components will not be transferred directly.Because Multism considers some parts (like resistors, capacitors..) as virtual  components.